tooltip overflow being cut off by using overflow-y: auto;


body {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
}

.game-right {
    width: 250px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 40px;
}
#container,
#upgrade {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding-right: 20px;
    position: relative;

}

.tooltip-container {
    position: relative;

    z-index: 1;

}

.tooltip-container button {
    width: 100%;
}

.tooltip {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 105%;

    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-size: 14px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 9999;

    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}


.tooltip-container:hover .tooltip {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

.tooltip::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: -10px;

    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #333;
}
                  <div class="game-right">
                    <!-- Upgrades section -->
                    <div id="container" style="max-height: 800px; overflow-y: auto;">
                        <div class="section-title">Employees</div>
                        <div class="tooltip-container">
                            <button id="extraButton" onclick="extraAction();">Worker: $10 (0)</button>
                            <span class="tooltip" id="Workertooltip">Earns $1.5 per second</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>



So basically, I want a div to be able to scroll when there is too much content, but when I use the overflow-y: auto; the tooltips get cut off. (Here is the Jsfiddle, the spacing and stuff is scuffed but you can see that it gets cut off in the container. https://jsfiddle.net/kj5wLo4b/1/ )
I have tried changing the Z-index of many thing multiple times, and creating a DOM for it, but nothing has worked, I just want to be able to scroll on the container and not have the tooltips to be cut off lol. I also tried moving the position: relative from .tooltip into #container and a new .container as suggested in Tooltip element with absolute positioning being clipped by container with overflow: auto but that only made the tooltips completely disappear



body {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
}

.game-right {
    width: 250px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 40px;
}
#container,
#upgrade {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding-right: 20px;
    position: relative;

}

.tooltip-container {
    position: relative;

    z-index: 1;

}

.tooltip-container button {
    width: 100%;
}

.tooltip {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 105%;

    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-size: 14px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 9999;

    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}


.tooltip-container:hover .tooltip {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

.tooltip::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: -10px;

    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #333;
}



                  <div class="game-right">
                    <!-- Upgrades section -->
                    <div id="container" style="max-height: 800px; overflow-y: auto;">
                        <div class="section-title">Employees</div>
                        <div class="tooltip-container">
                            <button id="extraButton" onclick="extraAction();">Worker: $10 (0)</button>
                            <span class="tooltip" id="Workertooltip">Earns $1.5 per second</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>


Your tooltip is always going to the left of the container element because it is using position absolute, it goes where you are placing it relative to its positioned parent element, initially when you hover right: 105%; as there is no rule there to override that in your hover rule. Why not place it on top on hover and restructure your tooltip pseudo to look like it is on top? Override the positioning in the .tooltip-container:hover .tooltip rule.
